# Why do Objective-C APIs return implicitly unwrapped optionals?

Tags: ios, objective-c, interop, swift, option-type

I am rather perplexed by this.  If we take the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in `UITableView` for example, it's method signature is:

```
func cellForRowAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
```

And its return value is:

> An object representing a cell of the table or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.

That sounds like the perfect reason to use a standard optional.  In fact, since all pointer based types in Objective-C can be nil... it seems to make sense that all Objective-C pointer types should be imported as standard optionals.

I know from the WWDC talk that they say that for implicitly unwrapped optionals:

- Can be tested explicitly for nil
- Can directly access properties/methods of the underlying value
- Can be implicitly converted to its underlying value

And from Apple's [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_31):

> When you access the value in this kind of optional type without safely unwrapping it first, the implicitly unwrapped optional checks whether the value is missing. If the value is missing, a runtime error occurs.

So, instead of importing a possibly nil value into Swift as an optional, they decided to import it as something that states that this should never be nil... but could be?  It sounds like they completely negated the safety of the optional type in Swift for Objective-C APIs by doing this.  What do I seem to be missing?

Instead of giving a compile time error or warning, they decided a runtime error was better?  This is very confusing.

Considering that nothing seems to answer this question that I have seen... I am thinking it is something obvious to everybody else that I am just not seeing but... Why is it like this?

Is it really just to save people from using `if let` or optional chaining when they use Objective-C APIs in Swift, or something more?

Answer (score 6):

When you make an implicitly unwrapped optional in Swift, it does not mean that it is always going to be non-nil: all it means is that you tell the compiler that when you access their properties, you expect the object to be non-`nil`. The object that you reference can be explicitly checked for `nil`; setting it to `nil` will not cause an exception either, unless you try to access any of its properties after that.

When Apple used implicitly unwrapped optionals for the parameters of

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
```

function, they let you save on a few extra `if` - `let`. In this case, they know that they never pass you a `nil`; in other cases, they do not know it, and they expect you to `nil`-check the object.

They allow you to return `nil`, too. It is up to them to check the results for `nil`, unless, of course, you decide to call that function yourself. Although I cannot think of a valid reason to call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` from your own code, if you do make a call, it would be your responsibility to check the return value for `nil`.

If you consider an alternative of making the parameters `UITableView?` and `NSIndexPath?` instead, all implementations would have to either use an exclamation point after `tableView` and `indexPath`, or use the `if` - `let` idiom. Compared to this choice, implicitly unwrapped types look like a better choice.

Comment: But couldn't the return value from the function be a UITableViewCell? ?  Why not make it a normal optional instead of an implicitly unwrapped one?

Comment: @NickH Yes, that would have worked, too, but it would make it less convenient for programmers who use their API. When `UITableView` calls you back on the data source, you can safely assume that both parameters are non-`nil`. The only reason that they are optional is Objective-C interoperability: in a native Swift API both parameters would probably be non-optional.

Comment: "they effectively made a promise to you that neither the tableView nor the indexPath that they pass to you would be nil" Nope. There is no such "promise". *All* object pointer types in Objective-C APIs imported into Swift *automatically* become implicitly-unwrapped optionals; there is no intelligence involved. Many of these APIs can (and in fact are supposed to) return `nil` under certain circumstances.

Comment: @newacct Hence my confusion, that seems like a place somebody would want to use a normal optional.  Implicitly Optional just makes it a bit easier to write as Swift more like Objective-C when using Objective-C APIs, but it appears to negate the safety of a normal optional.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I am actually more confused by the return value being an implicitly unwrapped optional instead of a normal optional.  If we think instead of soemthing somebody is more likely to call, like laterDate on NSDate (`func laterDate(_ anotherDate: NSDate!) -> NSDate!`) it returns an Implicitly unwrapped NSDate.  Why not just a standard optional NSDate, instead of an implicitly unwrapped one?

Comment: @NickH: It's a tradeoff between absolute safety and convenience. Since it could potentially be `nil` it must be optional. Implicitly-unwrapped makes it more convenient for you in the cases when you are sure that it's not `nil` (and if you're wrong, it throws an error), just like if you explicitly unwrapped it everywhere. If you are not sure it's not `nil`, you can still use optional binding and optional chaining. So basically you the programmer can choose the appropriate way to use it. This way Apple doesn't have to go through and explicitly annotate nullable/non-nullable in the whole API.

Comment: @newacct Thanks for that answer.  That is pretty much what I wanted to know.

Comment: Has anybody found out how we can 'annotate' our custom Objective-C APIs to specify how they should be mapped to Swift?

Answer (score 5):

The following was [Greg Parker's answer](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20170529/005502.html) in [swift-users](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/) at lists.swift.org:

> Importing as implicitly-unwrapped optional is a usability
>   **compromise**. Most Objective-C pointers are never actually nil. If a pointer is nil, and the author didn't check, then the process
>   deliberately halts. This is no worse than the behavior you get when
>   writing Objective-C code.
>       IUO import is intended to be a stopgap. I**n the long term every Objective-C interface ought to be explicitly annotated so that Swift
>   can import them more precisely.** In your own code you can use
>   NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN/END in your header files. Every un-annotated
>   object pointer inside those markers is nonnull.