# Matching ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional in a switch statement

Tags: swift

I'm trying to use a switch case to match a type of a generic, but I'm not sure how to match `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional`'s.

Imagine the function:

```
enum AttributeName: String {
    case someFloat = "someFloat"
    case someTint = "SomeTint"
}

func defaultValue<T>(_ name: AttributeName) -> T {
    switch name {
        case .someFloat:
            return CGFloat(8.0) as! T
        case .someTint:
            return UIColor.blue as! T
    }
}

func attribute<T>(_ name: AttributeName) -> T? {

    let attributes: [AttributeName: Any] = [AttributeName.someFloat: 10.0,
                                            AttributeName.someTint: UIColor.red]

    switch T.self {
    case is CGFloat.Type:
        guard let aFloat = attributes[name] as? Float
            else { return nil }
        return CGFloat(aFloat) as? T
    case is CGColor.Type:
        guard let color = attributes[name] as? UIColor
            else { return nil }
        return color as? T
    default:
        guard let attribute = attributes[name] as? T
            else { return nil }
        return attribute
    }
}


let button = UIButton()
button.layer.cornerRadius = attribute(AttributeName.someFloat) ?? defaultValue(AttributeName.someFloat)
button.backgroundColor = attribute(AttributeName.someTint) ?? defaultValue(AttributeName.someTint)
button.tintColor = attribute(AttributeName.someTint)
```

The above works fine if you try to call:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.layer.cornerRadius = attribute("float") // will be 10.0
button.backgroundColor = attribute("tint") // will be red
```

But trying to assign the button's `tintColor` will return a `nil` because the type of `T` will be an `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<UIColor>`. I.e:

```
button.tintColor = attribute("tint") // will be nil
```

I think I know what an ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional is and why Apple uses them ([by reading this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728235/why-do-objective-c-apis-return-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals)). But how do I match `tintColor` in this case?

I could do: `let tint: UIColor = attribute("tint")` and assign `tint` to the button's `tintColor`.
But is manually creating a `UIColor` and assigning it to `tintColor` really the only way?

Comment: Honestly, I would completely sidestep your issue by using a better type to represent your data. What happens if I do `button.layer.cornerRadius = attribute("tint")`? What about `button.backgroundColor = attibute("float")`? What if I do `something = attibute("This is a string, so it counts, right?")`?

Comment: Your `attribute` function does not compile, it does not return *anything* in the CGColor case, is that your real code? – `button.layer.cornerRadius = attribute("float") ` does not compile (optional not unwrapped). – If I fix these issues then I cannot reproduce the problem, `button.tintColor = attribute("tint")` works as well.

Comment: @MartinR And `attributes` needs a type annotation `[String : Any]`

Comment: @Alexander I've trivialised a lot of type checking to make sure things won't go bogus...the `name` param is a actually a type not a `String`. Moreover I've always got a fallback value for in case the `attribute` returns a `nil` as you tried in assigning the `Float` to the `backgroundColor`. In that case it would provide a default `UIColor` instead.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry I made a mistake there, it should've returned `color`.

Comment: @Gee.E: Posting a simplified example is a good thing, but it should still compile *and* exhibit the problem! – Please update the question accordingly.

Comment: Your updated code still does not compile in Xcode 9/Swift 4. A [mcve] is needed.

Comment: @Gee.E Returning a `nil` that's silently assigned isn't error checking. It's like error suppression. Something went very wrong (e.g. somebody gave an invalid parameter), and it will just fail silently, until you eventually realize funky things are going on. It's better to be explicit.

Comment: I updated my code and while doing so I discovered my error. I also discovered that there is a much better way to achieve what I'm trying to do, much more by reading the comments you two made.

Comment: @Gee.E: I am glad that your problem is solved. But please note that your question as it stands is not useful for future readers. The code *still* does not compile (AttributeName is not defined), so I don't know if it actually exhibits the described problem. Future readers searching for "Matching ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional" do not find useful information here.

Comment: Sigh, I'm sorry I was not paying attention; forgot to add the enum as well.

Comment: @Gee.E: Your code compiles and runs now, but it does not exhibit the described problem. `print(button.tintColor)` prints `UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1` (which is "red").

Comment: That is very weird, then I'm even more confused as of why I do get the problem. But that also means that my question is not really viable; sorry for causing noise then. I'll delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a better type to represent your data, sidestepping your issue? Perhaps something like this:

```
struct ButtonStyle {
    // If some of these proprties need to be optional (i.e. they're not always
    // set as part of a style) then comment below and I'll modify this accordingly
    cornerRadius: CGFloat
    backgroundColor: UIColor

    init(cornerRadius: CGFloat, backgroundColor: UIColor) {
        self.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    }

    // If you need to initialize ButtonStyle objects from dictionaries 
    // (e.g. from JSON), you can use this.
    // However, using `Codable` instead is ***greatly*** preferred.
    init?(fromDict dict: [String: Any] {
        guard let cornerRadius = dict["float"] as? CGFloat,
              let backgroundColor = dict["color"] as? UIColor {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(cornerRadius: cornerRadius, backgroundColor: backgroundColor)
    }
}

extension UIButton {
    var style: ButtonStyle {
        get {
            ButtonStyle(cornerRadius: self.layer.cornerRadius,
                        backgroundColor: self.backgroundColor)

        }
        set {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = newValue.cornerRadius
            self.backgroundColor = newValue.backgroundColor
        }
    }
}

let buttonStyle = ButtonStyle(cornerRadius: 10, backgroundColor: UIColor.red)
let button = UIButton()
button.style = buttonStyle
```

Comment: I agree, while re-writing my code I discovered that this is much better to do. Not only does it never goes wrong, it is more explicit then what I was doing. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Gee.E Indeed! Whenever you have a Dictionary of a fixed-set of keys (or subset of keys), whether they be string literals, constants, enums, or whatever, it's almost always better to use a struct or class instead. Would recommend: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_S6UOrwS-Tg

Comment: Ah, will definitely watch it later on today. Many thanks!